# Automatically update time in PHP using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

how automatically update the time in PHP using Ajax..the below command work by refreshing the page by hit f5 or reload button..

```
echo date('s');
```

or if it is necessary to update time by only using AJAX in php..

Comment: you want update time every second by ajax ?

Comment: After quick google search http://www.sitepoint.com/auto-refresh-div-content-jquery-ajax/

Comment: yeah i just want that second is dynamically update no need to refresh the page manually @SelVaa

Comment: @JohnCartwright i just want to update the second not the whole content the code you given is looking a little bit messy..

Comment: @SajjadKhan why would you want to do this? BOTH PHP and JS can log time separately? Can you give more insight so I can work out a solution for you

Comment: @Daniel i just want to update the time Automatically regardless what ever the solution it will be?

Comment: @SajjadKhan so sort of like a running timer but instead with the current time?

Comment: @Daniel yeah you are right

Comment: @SajjadKhan take a look at my answer. Don't forget to accept it if that's what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically this can be done using php and AJAX. Lets say you have two files index.php and timer.php. You can achieve your desired results by doing the following.

**In Index.php**

```
 <?php

echo "<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             setInterval(_initTimer, 1000);
         });
         function _initTimer(){
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'timer.php',
                 success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                     data = data.split(':');
                     $('#hrs').html(data[0]);
                     $('#mins').html(data[1]);
                     $('#secs').html(data[2]);
                 }
             });
         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id='hrs'>0</span>:<span id='mins'>0</span>:<span id='secs'>0</span>
    </body>
</html>";
```

**In timer.php**

```
 <?php echo date('h:i:s A');
```

Comment: @SajjadKhan You sure you followed the instructions? worked fine for me. Re-edited by copying and pasting the exact code I tried. Please try it again cos works perfectly for me

Comment: Yeah and one more thing in both of your pages are you forget to close the php blog?

Comment: Did it work? I'm not forgetting to close them. You don't have to close <?php tags for it to work

Answer (score 3):

You can use html5 server send event,The EventSource object is used to receive server-sent event notifications:

demo.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_sse.php file

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('s');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

if you have doubt let me know

Comment: no its not the area of my interest i just want to update the time dynamically or auto update the time?

Comment: tell me how please i just use the single function that is date and the parameter is date('s')..

Comment: i have update my answer, the event source function execute every second without refresh page

Comment: it shows that error in console      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test.php.

Comment: finally its work but it show second after 5 second gap and show the previous time also?

Comment: sorry i didn't get u ?

Comment: i mean it shows the previously time also?? why the latest replace the older one automatically?

Comment: try document.write(event.data) instead of  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";  or you can use jquery function $("#result").html(event.data);