# Automatically update time through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to automatically update time through ajax. but my code is not work. can anybody tell me what is the problem in my code. Here is my code....

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         setInterval(_initTimer, 1000);
     });
     function _initTimer(){
         $.ajax({
             url: 'ajax_timer.php',
             success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                 data = data.split(':');
                 $('#hrs').html(data[0]);
                 $('#mins').html(data[1]);
                 $('#secs').html(data[2]);
             }
         });
     }
    </script>
```

and here is my ajax_timer code

```
 <?php 
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
   echo date('h:i:s A'); 
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: What do you get as output? Show us some outputs.

Comment: what is the output of `data` ?

Comment: where's the html for this? and get in the habit of closing questions

Comment: i also include the jquery library file and run on the server. its work properly if ajax_timer file run in the browser but through ajax call its not working.

Comment: i want get input in the this code.

Comment: I test it work fine,maybe you missing library jquery,try add jquery link to your code.

Comment: <span id='hrs'>0</span>:<span id='mins'>0</span>:<span id='secs'>0</span>

Comment: it works now. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question that has been asked a year ago as" Automatically update time in PHP using Ajax" which has been solved.

So, to find the solution of your question go through it. [Automatically update time in PHP using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761823/automatically-update-time-in-php-using-ajax)